# Indexed Views in Sybase

Tags: indexing, sap-ase

Is it possible to create indices on views in Sybase (> ASE 12.5)?

Comment: Shouldn't the view be a materialised view?

Comment: @Vincent: in Microsoft SQL Server, views automagically get materialized when you create an index on them.  In fact, I think there is no way to explicitly create a materialized view.

Comment: I have no real need at the moment. Just needed to know definitively if it was possible or not. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried and got this error:

```
create view zzz_xyz as select * from sample_table
go
create index xxxxx on zzz_xyz  (sample_column)
go
```

Comment: Burcin, thanks for you example. I tried the same thing on ASE 12.5. Would you know if this is possible with ASE > version 12.5?

Comment: index data is stored in the pages related with data pages. 'views' are dynamic shortcuts therefore it is not possible logically.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create index on views becauce view is not a physical entitity. its just a view defination(sql query) execute when view is called.

You can create index on base tables which can be accessed while view is called